# SQL query to obtain average price on most recent invoices by company and product

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by, average, window-functions

Table is set up as below:

I'm trying to get an average of the last 7 invoices by product code and by company.

| Company | Product_Code | Price | Invoice Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | XYZ | 10 | 01012023 |
| B | XYZ | 11 | 01012023 |
| C | XYZ | 12 | 01012023 |
| A | ABC | 12 | 01022023 |
| B | ABC | 13 | 01022023 |
| C | ABC | 14 | 01022023 |
| A | LMN | 15 | 01022023 |

I tried something like:

```
SELECT 
    t1.company, t1.product_code, AVG(price) 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        Table
    ORDER BY invoice_date DESC 
    LIMIT 7) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.company, t1.product_code, t1.price
HAVING t1.company = 'A' or t1.company = 'B' or t1.company = 'C'
```

But this is just returning the last 7 invoices from the table-- how can I get the last 7 invoices by company and product code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for the last 7 by `Invoice Date` for all rows:

```
SELECT company, product_code, AVG(price) 
FROM a
WHERE "Invoice Date" IN (SELECT TOP 7 "Invoice Date" FROM a ORDER BY "Invoice Date" DESC)
GROUP BY company, product_code
```

This will do it for last 7 for each `company/product code` combo:

```
SELECT a.company, a.product_code, AVG(a.price) FROM a
JOIN (SELECT company, product_code, MIN("Invoice Date") "Invoice Date" FROM a WHERE "Invoice Date" IN (SELECT TOP 7 "Invoice Date" FROM a ORDER BY "Invoice Date" DESC) GROUP BY company, product_code) b
    ON a.company = b.company AND a.product_code = b.product_code AND a."Invoice Date" = b."Invoice Date"
GROUP BY a.company, a.product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions! This is likely to be more efficient than self-joins or subqueries, since it scans the table only once (... and the syntax is neater):

```
select company, product_code, avg(price) as avg_price
from (
    select a.*
    from a
    qualify row_number() over(partition by company, product_code order by invoice_date desc) <= 7
) a
group by company, product_code
```